# How can I pull data from a text file using Python?

Tags: python

Here is the example text:

```
ACCESSION NUMBER:           0001054274-12-000001
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  D
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
ITEM INFORMATION:           Rule 506
FILED AS OF DATE:           20120301
DATE AS OF CHANGE:          20120301
EFFECTIVENESS DATE:         20120301

FILER:

COMPANY DATA:   
    COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:               Alliqua, Inc.
    CENTRAL INDEX KEY:                    0001054274
    STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:   SURGICAL & MEDICAL INSTRUMENTS & APPARATUS [3841]
    IRS NUMBER:                           582349413
    STATE OF INCORPORATION:               FL
    FISCAL YEAR END:                      1220A
```

I am trying to pull all of the variables (Accession Number, Conformed Submission Type, ... , Fiscal Year End) and eventually write them to a .csv file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would look at the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [input and output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: what's the point of pasting a form response saying no one's going to write their code for them if you then do exactly that?

Comment: @Wooble: I didn't give a complete answer. It would still help if more detail was provided, or any effort was shown. It could help better if there was more information provided, and the goal is to teach the OP how to ask better questions, not to wash my hands of the problem. I am not trying to punish anyone for not providing a better question.

Comment: @Wooble: Maybe it's to reduce competition for his own answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd split the lines up by the first `:` and strip the results:

```
data = {}
with open(filename) as inputf:
    for line in inputf:
        if not ':' in line:
            continue
        label, value = map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
        if label and value:
            data[label] = value
```

which outputs the following mapping:

```
{'ACCESSION NUMBER': '0001054274-12-000001',
 'CENTRAL INDEX KEY': '0001054274',
 'COMPANY CONFORMED NAME': 'Alliqua, Inc.',
 'CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE': 'D',
 'DATE AS OF CHANGE': '20120301',
 'EFFECTIVENESS DATE': '20120301',
 'FILED AS OF DATE': '20120301',
 'FISCAL YEAR END': '1220A',
 'IRS NUMBER': '582349413',
 'ITEM INFORMATION': 'Rule 506',
 'PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT': '1',
 'STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION': 'SURGICAL & MEDICAL INSTRUMENTS & APPARATUS [3841]',
 'STATE OF INCORPORATION': 'FL'}
```

Comment: I got this error:

    7         if not ':' in line:
    8             continue
    ----> 9     label, value = map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
    10     if label and value:
    11         data[label]=value

    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @RossG: My apologies, there was an indentation gaffe in my answer. Fixed now.

Comment: +1: That is really pretty Python!

Comment: Wow thank you.  How would I output the variables to a .csv file?

I have tried this:

    tmp = open('F:/python/regd/2012/test.csv','wb')
    forOut=csv.writer(tmp)
    entry=[]

And then something like vars=(a, b, c, d)
    entry.append(vars)
    for row in entry:
        forOut.writerow(row)

That works but I don't quite know how to single out the individual variables

Comment: @RossG: You have only one row of data here, is my guess. You could use  a `csv.DictWriter` for that. Read documentation, try things out, ask in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20309/everything-python) perhaps, and if you have another concrete problem, perhaps ask another question.